# Conditional rowwise sum of subset of columns in specific row dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My problem is a bit tricky: I'm working on data edition and I'm close to finding the right solution. Got a dataframe like this:

```
ID   name   var1  var2  var3 var_total
1     a       1     1    2       4
2     b       2     3    2       7
3     c       1    -1   -1       1
```

Where `var_total` is the sum from var1 to var3 of each number that is higher than zero. Say, on ID == 2 I needed to change var2 to -1, doing this:

```
 df %>% mutate(var2 = if_else(ID == 2, -1, var2))
```

Which brings this:

```
ID   name   var1  var2  var3 var_total
1     a       1     1    2       4
2     b       2    -1    2       7
3     c       1    -1   -1       1
```

The problem is, I need to find a way to automatically re-calculate `var_total` for that row. I know how to do it for the whole dataframe, but that's a bit slow:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(var_total = {
    x <- c_across(starts_with('var'))
    sum(x[x > 0])
    })
```

Is there any way to perform this operation only on the selected `ID`? In this case, my final dataframe would be:

```
ID   name   var1  var2  var3 var_total
1     a       1     1    2       4
2     b       2    -1    2       4
3     c       1    -1   -1       1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to efficiently update a single row (or small subset of rows) I would use direct assignment, not `dplyr`.

```
var_cols = grep(names(df), pattern = "var[0-9]+", value = T)
recalc_id = 2
df[df$ID %in% recalc_id, "var_total"] = apply(df[df$ID %in% recalc_id, var_cols], 1, \(x) sum(x[x > 0]))
```

As akrun points out in comments, if it is just a single row, the `apply` can be skipped:

```
i = which(df$ID == recalc_id)
row = unlist(df[i, var_cols])
df$var_total[i] = sum(row[row > 0])
```

Here's the same thing with `dplyr::case_when`, for a `dplyr` solution:

```
df = df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(var_total = case_when(
      ID %in% 2 ~{
        x <- c_across(starts_with('var[0-9]+'))
        sum(x[x > 0])
      },
      TRUE ~ var_total
    )
  )
```

(Note that in both cases we need to change the column name pattern to *not* include `var_total` in the sum.)

`rowwise` breaks some vectorization and slows things down, so if you are so concerned about efficiency that recalculating the sum is "too slow", I'd strongly recommend the `base` solution. You might even find a non-conditional base solution to be plenty fast enough for this row-wise operation.

Comment: Thank you. As I'm working in a group we're encouraged to use `dplyr` as much as we can for better code readability, but this might be a good case for an exception

Comment: Yes, I like `dplyr` a lot too, but this is a case where I don't find it particularly readable. In either case I'd probably include a comment to say something like "recalcuate var_total for selected rows only."

Comment: @akrun strongly agreed. I'll edit with some commentary

Comment: Also, you don't need the `apply` i.e. `un1 <- unlist(df[i1, var_cols]); df$var_total[i1] <- sum(un1[un1 > 0])` (assuming a single row update)